# Extract array of array from properties file

Tags: java, arraylist

This is the value in the properties file:

`case.value =76,F,F,(ABC,DEF);77,F,F,(GHI,JKL)`

Can anybody tell me how to extract a `List<List<String>>` from this value? The first array should be separated by `;` and the internal array should be separated by `,`.

Example:

```java
@Value("#{'${case.value}'.split(';')}") 
List<String> case // but this will give only List which will get separated  by ; but I want List of List String splitted by ';' and ','
```

Can anybody help in this solution?

Comment: Do the brackets matter somehow? Can you add the expected output please?

Answer (score 2):

By first splitting the `String` with `";"` Then mapping each item for a List, you will get what would you like, for example:

```
        String s = "76,F,F;77,F,F;";
        Arrays.stream(s.split(";"))
            .map(sub -> sub.split(","))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

As @Lino explained this example will lead you to `List<String>`

better approach (thanks to him) will be like:

```
        String s = "76,F,F;77,F,F;";
        Arrays.stream(s.split(";"))
            .map(sub -> Arrays.asList(sub.split(",")))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This will yield `List<String[]>` you could convert the inner array to a `List` using `.map(Arrays::asList)`  or `.map(List::of)`

Comment: @Lino nice call!! updating